# How do you update a vue interpolation using an onclick method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am struggling to update the interpolation of `thing`.
This simple function should change the value of the data but instead does nothing.
Chrome logs the change of thing in the console but the HTML does not update.

```
<template>
  <div class="container-xl pb-5">
    <button class="mb-2 btn-lg selected-dropdown" @click="dropSelect('B')">
      {{ thing }}
    </button>
  </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      thing: "A",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    dropSelect(thing: any) {
      console.log(thing);
      return this.thing;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your data property instead of returning:

```
dropSelect(thing: any) {
  this.thing = thing
},
```

Answer (score 1):

One small observation **:** Use `this.thing = thing` instead of return `this.thing`

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    thing: "A"
  },
  methods: {
    dropSelect(thing) {
      this.thing = thing;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="dropSelect('B')">
      {{ thing }}
    </button>
</div>
```